# How do I keep button disabled until a form is filled out in Android?

Tags: android, button

My mobile app has three views (radio buttons, edittext text field, and a button).  I'm trying to keep the button disabled until a radio button is selected and text is entered into the text field.

I begin with `calc_button.setEnabled(false)`, so the button is initially disabled. My issue is since the user can use the radio buttons or text field in any order, I can't `setEnabled(true)`at the end of one of their listeners.

What concept does one apply in this situation?

Comment: Overly long title without the word Android. Consider making your post clearer. Overly wordy.

Comment: My first post.  I thought putting android in the title would be redundant with the android tag.  Added that and removed the info about me learning Android and things I had tried / my ideas.

Comment: I put booleans in the onclick listeners for the radiogroup and edittext that set to true when they were used and then at the end of both listeners, checked both for true and enabled the button if so.  I don't feel like this is the best solution, but it works for now.

Comment: Absolutely no problem :). Just that I like to get the idea what the qw is about from only scanning. Keep up the good work. (If I had thougt your qw was a good one I had upvoted it imediately just because you where new here).

Answer (score 0):

you can use a while loop inside an `AsyncTask` that keeps checking the states of both the radio button and the text field/`EditText` and then modify the button's state inside the `onPostExecute()`

Comment: I looked into that and it looked like it could accomplish this, but seems overly complicated for simply making sure the two inputs were used.  There must be a simple technique or method I could apply to make sure the inputs were used.  Thanks for introducing me to AsyncTask.